# How do we handle overlap with mathoverflow

Tags: discussion

This question is similar to the question "How to answer R questions" [How to answer R questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-answer-r-questions)
but for math.

Hence, if people ask math question, we can

1. Bounce them all to MO
2. Answer all questions, even when it's clearly mathematic and not statistics.

Certainly the "poblem" won't as frequent as with R questions but the frontier between math and statistic is not clear at all and it will be dificult to know and define if a question has "too much math" or not.

I would say 2, with a possible redirection when we believe that a better answer will be gievn by the math community...

We already have an example of overlap (however I don't think this one is a problem)
[Introduction to statistics for mathematicians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414/intro-to-statistics-for-mathematicians)

Answer (score 2):

My feeling is that this will depend on the kind of 'experts' that use this site. A few examples: (a) Theoretical questions on measure theory can be bounced to MO if no one here can answer them, (b) Very basic questions involving probability can be bounced to https://math.stackexchange.com/ or perhaps answered here itself. Anything in between basic probability and measure theory we should be able to handle.

Comment: See this question for an example of a basic probability question that can be bounced to http://math.stackexchange.com/: 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326/calculating-the-probability-of-two-dice-getting-at-least-a-1-or-a-5