# Probability questions: reaching stats.SE, math.SE, and MO audiences

Tags: discussion, on-topic, migration

There have already been a few questions on the relationship among stats.SE, math.SE, and MO.

It seems that mathematical probability questions are equally acceptable on all three. 
Some meta posts indicating this include:
[Are Pr questions allowed](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/432/are-probability-questions-allowed)
and
[How to handle overlap w/ MO](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-do-we-handle-overlap-with-mathoverflow).

The distinction that MO is generally reserved for higher level questions is often made, however, there is, of course, a gray area for "high level."

I also posted this question on meta: 
[Is it acceptable to post the same question on multiple sites](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/896/is-it-acceptable-to-post-the-same-question-on-multiple-sites)
which received a resounding "No!"

However, the audiences on each do appear to be different.  The probability tag on math.SE has 110 followers, and the probability tag on stats.SE has 17 followers (and I can't find a number on the pr.probability tag on MO).  The "high users" on each don't appear to have much overlap.

So, out of etiquette, one should only post on one site at a time. But if it is a question that is equally valid on all sites, it is more likely to get answered if more people are exposed to it.

So, my questions are:  is there a way you can migrate your own question from one site to another if it hasn't been answered?  If so, what is the appropriate time frame to wait for an answer on the first site?  If not, is it appropriate to delete the original question entirely from the first site and then re-post it on another site? I don't want to remove a question that people might find interesting, esp. if it's gotten comments and interest.  But I would like to expose it to a wider audience if necessary.

Comment: As I wrote in my "No!" answer, this is a manner of trusting the community -- if the question have a little chance of being answered or is off-topic, it will probably get a feedback suggesting where to possibly relocate it and may be migrated. And this way is just clearer and overall more effective then prespreading the Q to all possible sites.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can migrate a question by flagging it yourself, which allows you to send a message to all moderators with your request.  It's hard to imagine a circumstance in which this would be denied (unless the question is too ill-posed, in which case it would just be closed anyway).

BTW, I wouldn't read too much into audience size.  My experience with the math and stats sites is that when stats questions involve *anything* to do with actual data, you are far better off posting on the stats site.  When the questions are theoretical, as yours have been, it's hard to know where to go.  A clear, well-posed question will get attention on both sites.  If it turns out that the answer needs simulation, data analysis, or research, you're likely to get that answer here.  If it succumbs to purely mathematical techniques, math.SE is probably the best place for it.  But it's often hard to know in advance what the solution will look like.  In that case guess, wait a few days, and have the question migrated if there's no useful response.

Comment: correct, taking this to an extreme, the only "audience size" necessary is one, *if it just so happens to be the right person*. And asking a programming question on the world's largest videogame site isn't going to produce great results either. It's all about the *correct* audience. That said, "this is not getting properly answered" is one of the the key reasons to migrate..

Answer (score 5):

Here is the example of [one question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63134/a-sequence-of-order-statistics-from-an-iid-sequence). It was asked on stats.SE, I gave a bounty on it. After nobody answered it was migrated to math.SE, and then I gave bounty there. In the end I've posted it on MO, from my own account (I was not the one who asked the question in the first place). The question was finally answered on MO.

So my advice with the question for posting the question would the following.

1. Pick either math.SE or stats.SE. Ask the question.
2. If nobody answers propose bounty.
3. If nobody answers then, ask the admins to migrate the question to either math.SE or stats.SE
4. If nobody asks then, ask it on MO, mentioning the history.