# What is the appropriate course of action dealing with overzealous redirection?

Tags: discussion

[Elsewhere](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions) in meta it seems like the consensus has arisen that generally questions related to statistical programing languages should be accepted here.  Yet, some users haven't gotten the memo and continue to redirect earnest question answers to StackOverflow.  When I see this behavior I've been adding comments redirecting them to the appropriate thread at meta.  However, with one repeat offender I simply flagged the comment.  What is the appropriate approach?  Is there a way to get all of the users on the parent site on the same page with meta?

Comment: Your title seems a bit misleading. The issue is 'commenting'/'redirecting'/perhaps 'downvoting' but it is definitely not 'moderation' as I do not think the moderators are involved. Is my assessment correct?

Comment: correct - I will edit

Comment: Many thanks for highlighting this information to new users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we just have to keep adding comments and pointing to the [scope thread on meta](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions). If you think it helps to have a moderator add the comment (although I'm not sure that it makes much difference), feel free to continue flagging posts or comments and one of us will respond ASAP. Unfortunately I don't think we can edit the faq yet.