# Should we "unclose" computing questions

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Following on from this [question](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252/should-we-allow-more-computing-questions) about extending scope, should we "unclose" previous computing questions. For example,

- [How can I get R to stop autocompleting my quotes/parens?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/944/how-can-i-get-r-to-stop-autocompleting-my-quotes-parens-closed)
- [What code would you put before/after your R session](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/what-code-would-you-put-before-after-your-r-session-closed)

I would say that since there is only a few questions, we may as well open them. That way people searching the archives won't get confused.

---

**Edit**

I've reopened the above questions. The only other question I found that could be reopened is:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/ruby-statistical-gem-closed

Should I reopen this question? Are there other questions I've missed?

Comment: why not ? ok for me too

Comment: Yes to the ruby qn also. That is a bit more borderline but I think we should open it to be consistent.

Comment: I don't think that "data processing" is sufficiently within our scope to reopen the ruby gems question. It could mean statistical analysis, but it could also mean almost anything else to do with handling data.

Comment: I would open the ruby question - borderline, but OK.

Answer (score 5):

Makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

What about this question?  Is there any change in the consensus here?

- [Algorithms to compute the running median?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134/algorithms-to-compute-the-running-median)

Comment: It fits within "statistical computing" I think. I'll wait a day in case there are objections.

Comment: I vote open....

Comment: Now re-opened..